# How to repeat a function multiple times and sum the output in python?

Tags: python

I want to have a function repeat 12 times and sum up the output over the 12 iterations. Thus far I have tried:

```
def main():
    counter=0
    while counter <= 12:
        running = function()
        counter += 1
    x = sum(running)
    print(x)

main()
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `sum()` function with `range()`:

```
x = sum(experiment() for _ in range(12))
```

Answer (score 1):

You want something like this:

```
import random

def experiment():
    return random.randrange(10)

def main():
    sum = 0
    counter = 0
    while counter < 12:
        counter += 1
        result = experiment()
        sum = sum + result
    print(sum)

main()
```

Sample results (1 per run):

```
66

62

57
```